# Invalid image data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

my problem is that image_1 I displayed as logo in 'Xamarin.Forms.Image' worked good until i changed it to image_2. It did not work, so I changed it back to image_1. Now it does not work too and I got some errors:

```
[0:] Could not load image named: {0}: nurse.png
[0:] FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: nurse.png
[0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource
```

As I said, it was working before the change. My Xamarin.Forms.Image looks like this:

```
 <Image 
    x:Name="main_logo"
    Source="logo.png"
    Aspect="AspectFit" >
```

logo.png is in main Xamarin.Forms part of solution (where the App.xaml is).
I do not understand why it does not work now If it did before. Same error occurs when i try to make ImageButton. I tried to clean/rebuild, delete all files from /bin folder and then rebuild, not working. Any help appreciated!

Comment: have you opened the image in an editor to verify that it is valid?

Comment: please read the docs on naming and file locations for images: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#local-images

Comment: @Jason looks like I made some mistakes when locating the files. I think I saw a comment somewhere that I need to locate images in Xamarin.Forms main part of solution, relocated images to Android/drawable and it all works fine. Thank you.